# If $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $T(0)=0$, then $T$ is always a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm stumped on a true or false question I found in one of our practice worksheets for my Linear Algebra class. Would anyone mind answering this and explaining why as well?

**Question:** If $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $T(0)=0$, that is, $T$ maps the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, then $T$ is always a linear transformation.

I'm leaning towards "true" because of the following theorem: If $T$ is a linear transformation, then $T(0)=0$ and $T(cu+dv)=cT(u)+dT(v)$ for all vectors $u$ and $v$ in the domain of $T$ and all scalars $c$ and $d$.

Comment: When drowning in abstraction it always helps to think of some simple concrete examples. Let's assume $n = m = 1$ for simplicity. In this case can you give a few examples of functions $T:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy $T(0) = 0$?

Comment: I think I get it. Would it be correct to answer this item with "false" because of the following example: $T(x)=(cosx)$ because $T(0)=1$? Thanks! Edit: Actually, $T(x)=(cosx)$ might not be a linear transformation. Will check.

Comment: Good question. That is actually not a counterexample. In order to show that the answer is "false", you need to find a function which does satisfy $T(0) = 0$ and yet is not a linear transformation.

Comment: Oh I get it now! Didn't get it the first time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear transformations always maps zero to zero, since , for all scalars $c,d$,  $T(cu+dv)=c T(u)+dT(v)$ and so this true for $c=d=0$.   But the other direction is not true. Here is a simple example:

$$T:\Bbb R^2 \ni (x,y) \longmapsto (\sin x, 0) \in \Bbb R^2$$

Answer (score 4):

Of course not ! Take $m=n=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$